# A modern replacement for DH.82's Gipsy Major engine

Tags: piston-engine, modifications

While I deeply appreciate any vintage aircraft that is powered by their original engines, I was wondering if there are any modern replacement engines available for the *de Havilland Tiger Moth* aircraft with *Gipsy Major* engines installed that require no or minor modifications of either the aircraft and/or the engine itself?

Comment: That's a pretty unusual configuration these days - 4 inline cylinders, with the cylinders below the endine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Gipsy_Major#/media/File:DHGipsyMajorengineDrover.JPG

Certainly nothing like the flat-4 pancake engines used in modern Cessnas and Pipers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Avia (now LOM) M132](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOM_M132) 4 cylinder inverted inline might fit. Some adaptation work is probably required.

Comment: Seems it is used in the Fisher R-80 Tiger Moth. I don't know how I didn't think about that!

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.  The closest thing would be a Fairchild Ranger inverted in-line 6, almost as old and 70 lbs heavier and I don't think it's ever been tried.

The DHC-1 Chipmunk, DeHavilland Canada's first in-house design (and later license built by mother DH in UK), also used the Major, and a lot of them have been modified with opposed Lycomings, but I can't imaging anyone ruining the lines of a T Moth that way.